# How to fix ""code":"RequestBodyRead"" error?

Tags: javascript, ajax, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to make an outlook add-in that forwards an email using Microsoft API, but I am getting an error saying "comment" is not a valid parameter when it is according to the documentation. 
I am following the forwarding documentation:
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-forward?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#request-body)

```
var forwardMessage = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl +
  '/beta/me/messages/' + itemId + '/forward';
var body= JSON.stringify({
      "comment": item,
      "toRecipients": [
        {
          "emailAddress": {
            "address": "email@email.com",
            "name": "name"
          }
        }
      ]
    })
    $.ajax({
      url: forwardMessage,
      method:"POST",
      dataType: 'json',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
  'Content-Type': "application/json" },
  data: body
    }).then(
      console.log("done")
    )
  }).catch(function(error){
    throw error;
  });
```

The error:

```
{"error":{"code":"RequestBodyRead","message":"The parameter 'comment' in the request payload is not a valid parameter for the operation 'Forward'."}}
```

Comment: can you show the result of `JSON.stringify` ? i suspect the `item` has an issue. it should be a string.

Comment: Item is an object I am gettin back from another ajax call that gives me the email details. It is confidential so I cannot show you the result, but I tried "Hello World" instead of item and it still gave me that error.

Comment: Maybe it should be item.toString() as the parameter value for comment?

Comment: I fixed the error, I was using the wrong parameter and "comment" needed to be "Comment"